# On change does not work

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have created a new field in sale.order.line

`_columns = {
                'od_deivered_quantity':fields.float('Delivered 
                              Quantity',trackvisibility = onchange,readonly = False)
            }`

then I wrote the following onchange function:

```
@api.depends('product_uom_qty')
def onchange_delivered_order(self, cr, uid, ids,context=None):
   res = {}
   delivered_qty = self.product_uom_qty
   return {'value':{'od_delivered_qty':delivered_qty}}
```

XML code as follows:

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree//field[@name='product_uom_qty']" position="after">
              <field name = "od_delivered_qty"/>
          </xpath>
```

but it does not works

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but your code is a bit messy and buggy; furthermore it looks like you're mixing up old API style (pre-v8), as during fields declaration, and new one, for onchange method.

Let's recap, I wonder whether I understood well your requirements: you need a new field `od_deivered_quantity` being triggered by `product_uom_qty`. Is that right?

I suggest something like the following chunks (I'm gonna use new API style):

```
od_deivered_quantity = fields.Float(
    "Delivered Quantity", track_visibility="onchange", readonly=False
)

@api.onchange('product_uom_qty')
def onchange_delivered_order(self):
    # if isinstance(self.product_uom_qty, bool):
    #    return
    delivered_qty = self.product_uom_qty
    self.od_delivered_qty = delivered_qty
```

Please, try to inspect to this onchange method behaviour when it'll be up and running in your module: I put a commented boolean check into that, in case (because of any awkward reason) the method will be called passing a `False` value on product_uom_qty.

Talking about views, your XML may be OK because in new API style [https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#onchange-updating-ui-on-the-fly](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#onchange-updating-ui-on-the-fly/)

> both computed fields and new-API onchanges are automatically called by
>   the client without having to add them in views

Let me know whether it will work fine or you'll face any problems.

Comment: I tried your code but still the function didn't work. I didn't get any errors but the function is not working @dbrus

Comment: What does it mean that is not working? Does it return any error? Can you describe more precisely all the passages you are doing the program behaviour? Thanks

Comment: .if the function works, when I change the product_uom_qty's value the value of od_delivered_qty should also be changed  . It does not happens. The value of od_delivered_qty is 0 @dbrus

Comment: Sometimes it occurs that onchange methods are called twice rather than once, when the trigger field is changed. Your trigger field is float: if you are facing a multiple calls issue, `product_uom_qty` could be 0-value during the second call, ending up in `od_delivered_qty` reset to 0.
Please try just and debug the ochange method (or just print `product_uom_qty` value during the method call), in order to check what's going on inside that.

Comment: I have put a print inside that function. I can't see any prints on my console when I change the `product_uom_qty` .That means the function is not invoked(onchange function).